# Add a new row to Asp.net gridview without refreshing entire grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP.Net grid view for data entry. I want the following functionality:
When the focus is in the last row's last cell, on pressing tab key, a new row should get added to grid view. When new row is added, the entire grid should not get refreshed, i.e. only a new blank row should appear below the last row. Furthermore, After all data entry is done, on Save button click (lying outside the grid view) I want all the entered data in rows to be saved to database.
Please help me with this functionality.

Comment: This is not the place where you ask for the full code, please show us some code about what you tried?

Comment: If you got stuck with some code issue, we can try help you. We can't help you write the code. That's what google is for.

Answer (score 0):

Check this  [Code Project Example on Grid-view](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417693/Insert-Update-Delete-in-ASP-NET-Gridview-DataSourc) .

Hope this one helps you for building your idea about your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it will take a very nasty hack to achieve this, why? Microsoft designed the ASP.NET GridView control as a control which renders on the server side and then spits it's HTML markup to the clients browser. 
If you need to enable insertion on the client side, i suggest the following alternatives:

1. (Cheapest time cost) Keep the grid view, and enable the new record insertion by having a separate container on the page: such as a hidden Panel that has the input controls necessary to create a new record. The Panel can be easily displayed or hidden on the client side using plain JaveScript. When hitting "Save" the input data will be posted back to the server and added to your data store.
2. (Medium time Cost) Migrate to ASP.NET [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control. In a Repeater you have control on the FooterTemplate which can contain a last row of the table. populate this row with any input controls, surround this row with a container that will enable you the simply show/hide it, if the user triggers the tab key on the last row.
3. (Larger time Cost) Migrate to a client based grid control such as [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).